# Twitter bootstrap structure with divs

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I would like to know if its possible to move that bar a bit under, the bar is wrapped with a `<p>` tag.

```
<div class="span9 well">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2">
            <img src="dummy_image.jpg" class="img-polaroid">
        </div>
        <div class="span7">
            <h2>Title</h2>      
            <p>Texttttttttttttttttt.</p>
            <p >
                <a href="#"><span class="label label-info">Genre</span></a>
                <span class="label label-warning">
                <i class="icon-star"></i>
                ...<!-- stars -->
                </span>     
                <a href="#"><span class="label label-success">Yes</span></a> / <a href="#"><span class="label label-important">No</span></a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

screen shot of the actual block i wanna change:

[image]

Comment: CSS is your friend here. You need to customize a bit, but it's no big deal.

Comment: The answer bellow from @Wojciech Dłubacz worked, and the css its the Twitter-Bootstrap original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position:absolute`

```
.row-fluid{position:relative; width:450px; background:red; overflow:auto}
.span2{display:inline; float:left}
.span7{display:inline; }
.row-fluid > p{position:absolute; bottom:0; left:170px}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TJcz7/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for this one aswell. Using it :) and the other one aswell(on the fixed layout)

Answer (score 2):

You can always name your `<p>` tag like so:

```
<p class="bar">
    <a href="#"><span class="label label-info">Genre</span></a>
    <span class="label label-warning">
    <i class="icon-star"></i>
    ...<!-- stars -->
    </span>     
    <a href="#"><span class="label label-success">Yes</span></a> / <a href="#"><span class="label label-important">No</span></a>
</p>
```

then use `.bar {margin-top: 20px;}` in your css code, it's not bad behaviour

Comment: thanks :) i added this to my custom css file worked like a charm